# Lens options for a 18-55 and 50 1.8 plus a canon t2i owner

Tags: canon, canon-550d

I've got a canon T2i with the 18-55 IS II kit lens and a 50mm 1.8 prime. I sold back my 55-250 when i got the 50mm thinking i wouldn't need it. But i'm looking for a couple of different lenses now. I'm not sure what to get. I want to experiment more but somehow feel limited by the kind of photos i can take with these. I;m bored of taking standard portraits and close-ups...I'd like to shoot maybe a little bit on the wider end, or perhaps a wider prime... not sure.. what would be good lens setup? my budget is around $1000.. pls help! thanks! :)

Also, im open to replacing my existing 18-55 as well ;)

Comment: You already have two lenses. You just note that you "somehow feel limited" and are "looking for a couple of different lenses". We need a better understanding of what is limiting or what you are trying to photograph that you cannot not. Please be as specific as possible. As the question stands right now, every lens that you don't own could be considered a recommendation. Edit the question to include the detail please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lens upgrade paths (sub $1000) for the EF-S 18-55mm IS kit lens for Canon APS-C cameras](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/lens-upgrade-paths-sub-1000-for-the-ef-s-18-55mm-is-kit-lens-for-canon-aps-c)

Comment: @dpollitt: done.. i edited the post... i'm tired of taking portraits of people... somehow i fell they don't tell a story... i'd like a wider lens so i can capture a bit more of the surrounds as well, and get some amazing perspectives..

Comment: Also, what would be better a 35mm? or 28mm? considering what i already have..

Comment: I would recommend renting a couple of lens' that you are interested in to see if they are actually what you want/need. This is a great way to avoid buyers remorse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the eos 400D (a rebel), too, so I can share my experience:
I tossed my kit lens after buying Canon 28-135 USM IS - the images are just so much better with it. The drawback is that on a crop camera the field of view is not wide enough for some situations (like in the living room).

http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-28-135mm-f-3.5-5.6-IS-USM-Lens-Review.aspx

So a lens that goes further down is still needed, and if I had 1000euro I would get this one: EF-S 17-55 f/2.8 IS USM - It is a fixed aperture F/2.8 no matter how you zoom.

http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-S-17-55mm-f-2.8-IS-USM-Lens-Review.aspx

Notice the "mouse overs" where they compare to the kit lens. You can't believe how bad the kit lens is until you see that.

If you think that focal range is more important than low light shooting then I'd get this lens:

http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-S-15-85mm-f-3.5-5.6-IS-USM-Lens-Review.aspx

When I got the 28-135mm lens I paired it with Sigma 10-20mm HSM which makes some great wide angle shorts. With group pictures it is best to zoom int to 5-20mm though, or the people on the edges get long faces:

http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Sigma-10-20mm-f-4-5.6-EX-DC-Lens-Review.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The [Canon 10-22mm](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-S-10-22mm-f-3.5-4.5-USM-Lens-Review.aspx) replaces the fairly standard 16-35mm lens on a crop body camera (will not fit full frame cameras). This focal length is essential for landscape and architecture photographers, so it might be a good starting place for something new.  At the 35mm equivalent side of things, the lens will produce fairly straight images.  At 16mm, the edges will seem stretched out, but that is an effect of any super wide angle rectangular lens... the FOV is just so much wider than the human eye's.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your budget, there are some nice, high-quality lenses available from 3rd party vendors like Tamron, Tokina, Sigma etc. at a much lower cost than the Canon equivalents.

Wide angle:

- Tokina AF 11-16mm f/2.8
- Tokina AF 12-24mm f/4

Standard zoom (to replace your kit lens):

- Tamron SP 17-50mm f/2.8

Telephoto zoom:

- Tamron SP 70-300mm f/4-5.6 VC USD

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer already linked in the comments: [Lens upgrade paths (sub $1000) for the EF-S 18-55mm IS kit lens for Canon APS-C cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/lens-upgrade-paths-sub-1000-for-the-ef-s-18-55mm-is-kit-lens-for-canon-aps-c)

It sounds like you might be specifically interested in the Canon EF-S 10-22mm f/3.5-4.5 USM lens. It is specifically designed for your camera, being an EF-S lens, and provides a very wide angle view. The focal length between 10-17mm is what you would be adding and would give a very wide perspective for landscape or elemental shots. It would not be a good lens for portraits as it does introduce a significant amount of distortion, making noses and faces look very big.

Comment: thanks! that definitely helps.. i can live with no portraits for a while.. im just a hobbyist and just shooting what i like ;).
Also, can the 10-22 also work as a street / journalistic type of lens? i mean does it have too much distortion at the 22mm end for me to get a separate 28 or 35mm prime? thanks again!