# Canon 700D - 1 STM lens or 2 non-STM lenses for a beginner?

Tags: canon, canon-700d

This is my very first DSLR experience and after weeks of reading and watching videos online. I have decided 700D is what I need in the budget I have (40K – 45K INR). I have narrowed down to two kits:

http://www.canon.co.in/personal/products/interchangeable-lens-camera/dslr-eos/eos-700d-dual-kit?languageCode=EN

http://www.canon.co.in/personal/products/interchangeable-lens-camera/dslr-eos/eos-700dkit-efs18-55is-stm?languageCode=EN

They both cost me the same thing. I understand the first one offers 2 lenses but neither of those two is a STM whereas the second one offers only 18-55 which is a STM lens.

I cannot decide for myself. I read some forums online to understand the significance of STM lenses. They are “quiet” and have better auto focus.

While I am convinced that STM lenses are better than the non STM ones, does it really matter to a great extent for a beginner like me? I would be shooting more pictures than videos (70 % pictures and 30% videos). In that case, would it really be a deal breaker if I choose the 1st kit with two non-STM lenses?

Comment: The only thing we can help you with in understanding the difference between the two deals, and it seems you understand that pretty well already - which one is the right decision for you is something only you can decide as everybody's priorities are different.

Comment: 18-55 is a relatively small range. Depending on what kinds of pictures you take, you will probably want a lens that goes further (I don't know Canon, but my Nikon 18-105 is appreciable, I often use it at 105mm and I cannot always carry two lens with me). 20 years ago, you had to sacrifice a lot of quality to get more zooming, but this is much less true today. Don't just think about what you're buying now, but think about what next you may want to buy. Yeah, not really helping with the original question, I know ;-).

Comment: No ... I think you make sense to me. You are telling me to buy the 18-135 mm.. shame i do not have enough budget for that right now. It would cost me 53K

Comment: It's not about STM vs. non-STM. It's about 18-55mm & 55-250mm (non STM) vs. 18-55mm STM. :) What's more important to you: focal length coverage? or autofocusing smoothly and quietly?  Most of us would probably rate the importance of the focal length or maximum aperture of a lens above the focus motor type.  See also: [this question on a lens upgrade path for Canon APS-C shooters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/lens-upgrade-paths-sub-1000-for-the-ef-s-18-55mm-is-kit-lens-for-canon-aps-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I avoid "kits" because I want to chose my lens, so I buy the body and the lens separately.  You could consider buying a nicer, yet older, lens (used).  Be sure that it will work with your camera and is in good condition though; probably from a reputable reseller.  Good luck.

Comment: He is already struggling with the decision what lens is _nicer_

Comment: "She" Lol Things would have been simpler if I were a "he" , I guess. Oh well..