# Lens upgrade for Canon EOS 1100D

Tags: lens, canon

I have 18-55mm kit lens as well as 55-250mm, 50mm/f1.8 and 24mm/f2.8 lenses. What lenses should be required for upgrade in future?

Comment: 1200mm f/5.6. *Obviously*.

Comment: It depends a lot on what kind of photography you do. Personally, over the time, I replaced the 55-250mm by a Sigma 100-400 and a Canon 100mm macro. I also replaced the 18-55 by a Sigma 17-70 2.8/4. But everyone will have a different answer, because we all have different favorite subjects.

Comment: I love to take landscape photos as well as portrait when I am in outdoor

Comment: Do you understand what it is limiting you about your current equipment (not just lenses)? If not, then don't buy anything.

Comment: Maybe see: [Lens upgrade paths (sub $1000) for the EF-S 18-55mm IS kit lens for Canon APS-C cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8518)

Comment: The answer is unique to each user.  As you use your equipment,you will come to know if any of your gear is not meeting your needs.  It's at that time you will know what needs to be upgraded and why.  For example, if you're getting a lot of camera shake, a stabilized lens and/or a lens with a larger aperture would help fix this problem.  If you're having a sharpness problem, then an optically superior lens would be required.  Go to opticallimits.com for sharpness charts.Basically, if ain't broke, then don't fix it.

Answer (score 4):

> What lenses should be required for upgrade in future?

None.

There are plenty of photos you can take with the lenses you already have.

What photos do you wish to take that your current lenses limit you from taking?

You should consider another lens if:

- You envision photos that you have the knowledge and skill to pull off but that your current lenses can not execute due to a technical limitation of the lens.
- You can explain how another particular lens will solve the issue you are experiencing with your current lenses.