As a beginner, how do I figure out which lens to get next?
I have a Canon R50 camera and am looking for a more versatile lens.  I am looking at RF 24-104 STM 4 - 7.1 or with an adapter the EFS 18-135 3.5 5.6 USM
Also looking at a 18-250mm F3.5-6.3 DC MACRO
I'm kind of all over the place, suffering analysis paralysis, and a little confused. What do I need to consider when shopping for a lens? How do I make the right choice?

More versatile than... which one do you have?

I'm sorry to be blunt, but a beginner doesn't need to figure out what lens to get next. Photography isn't some kind of box-ticking exercise nor is it an exercise in filling a camera bag. Use the camera and lens you have. Look at photo books, go to exhibitions, and most of all, just go out and enjoy photography. Set yourself some projects, experiment, be creative, tell stories, develop your vision.

Here are some relevant previous questions: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8518/9161 https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3569/9161

Do you have the 18-45?  That seems to be the one packaged with the camera most often.

Related to why you may or may not be happy with using a 24-105mm lens on an APS-C camera, please see: Answers and comments to Will I see enough improvement moving from EF-S to "L" lenses to warrant the cost? and this answer to Beginner kit improvement advice - which lens should I consider?


I have a Canon R50 camera and am looking for a more versatile lens

More versatile than... which one do you have?

I would argue that the way of thinking is the opposite.
You probably have a kit lens. It is a general-purpose one. Now, based on a specific need or a specific limitation, you get a new one.
Examples of needs and limitations and a possible option.

I want bokeh on my portraits > Get one with a larger aperture.
I want the objects to look closer > Get a telephoto lens with a higher focal length.
I want shaper images > Get a prime lens.

And we can go on and on.
One side note. There is not "a mighty lens", that is ultra sharp, has a large zoom range, and ultra-wide aperture that can focus from a but to a planet. What you can get is a specialized lens for specific needs.

You're unlikely to get any good advice unless you specify what you want from a lens, in what way you want the lens to be a "more versatile" (than what? -- you didn't specify that either).
Lenses have a number of properties:

What are the focal length(s)
What is the maximum aperture (for low light or for background blur)
How close you can focus (macro or not)
How quick the autofocus is
How good the image quality is
How lightweight and small the lens is
Whether the lens is weather sealed
Whether the lens is image-stabilized and if so, how good the stabilization is
How expensive the lens is

Since you listed a number of superzooms, maybe you want a lens with lots of focal length options with a wide range. For an APS-C camera, I wouldn't recommend any lens that starts at 24mm, since you miss a lot of wide-angle focal lengths then. Also adapted lenses are arguably worse since you need a large and heavy adapter, so RF-S 18-150mm would be the natural option for a superzoom for APS-C sized RF mount. You have to however understand that superzooms typically have a small aperture and low image quality, cost more than non-superzooms and are heavier and larger than non-superzooms.
However, if focal length is not what you want but you rather want a large aperture for either low light or for background blur, your best option is some prime lens with wide aperture like a "nifty fifty" (50mm f/1.8).

RF lenses with the same focal lengths and maximum apertures tend to be longer and heavier than their EF counterparts. That's because effectively the "adapter" (i.e. the 24mm longer length needed to mate with a camera having 20mm registration distance instead of 44mm) is already a permanent part of the back end of the RF lens. The main reason the RF 70-200/2.8 is so much smaller (when compacted at 70mm) and lighter than the EF 70-200/2.8 is because the EF is a fixed length with internal zoom and the RF is not.


As a beginner, how do I figure out which lens to get next?

Ask yourself the question, "What kind of photo do I want to take that my current lens doesn't allow?"
Then find out what kind of lens can take that specific photo and get such a lens.
In a perfect world we'd all be able to afford a different lens for every photo we make. But that's not the real world.
So to modify the question above, ask yourself, "What kinds of photos do I want to take that my current lens doesn't allow?"
Then find out what kinds of lenses can cover the widest range of those kinds of photos while giving you acceptable (to you) image quality.
Until you tell us what lens(es) you currently have and what kind(s) of photos you want to take that you can't get with your current gear, we can't answer what lens would be best for you.
But in general, don't buy any new gear until you can articulate what it is that you want to do and that you are capable, as a photographer, of doing that the new gear can allow you to do that your current gear can't. This is the case whether talking about lenses, camera bodies, lighting and light modifiers, tripods, etc.

Did you mean for both links in your final paragraph to be to the same question?

Yes. It's two halves of what the link is about, and I didn't want to change the color of all three lines of text.

I am about six months into beginner photography, and some thoughts about beginner camera and lenses. I started with no specific ideas, but just to learn photography.
I use Nikon ZFC Mirrorless APSC camera, and this is somewhat similar to that of the R50 you have. I got one lens purchased separately (not a kit-lens). It is a prime lens, the Z 50mm f/1.8. The lens has a single focal length. Since, the camera is a APSC format, the prime lens gives an effective focal length of 75 mm.
A lens has two main parameters - the focal length and the maximum aperture. In my case it is the 50mm and the f/1.8 max aperture (and f/16 minimum aperture). These determine what kind of photographs you want to take. Aperture also determines how much light the camera can capture. These two aspects effectively determine the photography using the fundamental settings - aperture, shutter speed, focal length and ISO.
With a zoom lens, you have variable apertures and variable focal lengths. It gives flexibility, but you need clear understanding how these two main parameters work together to use effectively. For a beginner the only way to know this is by experience, that is practice. A zoom lens with wide aperture may not be budget friendly.
A prime lens may not have the flexibility, but it is easy to understand the main parameters and their capabilities. After a few months with this kind of lens and experience you can know how the two factors work together in various situations. You would also know what your primary interest in photography is. Then, you are likely to know well what lens (or lenses) you want. These lenses can be budget friendly.
Telling what kind of lens you presently have, and what kind of photos you had tried and what you feel is shortcoming is needed to get help with a good choice. Also, what kind of photography genre you have interest in helps to suggest what you are looking for.
Recently I started posting some photos I had taken on a public photos forum Flickr.

I am assuming you have the 18-45mm lens as that seems to be what is packaged with the camera most often.  I have the M6 Mk II, which is quite similar to your camera.  I got it with a 15-45mm initially.  The difference in the wide ends of the lenses is more than it looks like.  It comes up when you want to take a photo of a group of people and have to step back further to get them all in or when you want to take a travel photo of a building and don't have enough room.  I think there are three choices of next lenses in very different directions.  Each relieves a restriction of your current lens.  I would advise doing none of them until you feel which limit matters to you.
One is the RF-S 55-210.  It is the natural longer zoom for your camera.  If you are always shooting at 45mm and still aren't close enough this is the direction to go.  I have no use for the 24-105 you mention because the bottom half overlaps with the lens you have and the upper half doesn't go far enough.  I have the equivalent for my camera and use it a fair amount because it covers the pictures I see.
Another is the RF-S 10-18.  This gives you quite a bit wider range if that is what you want.  I have the equivalent 11-22 and use it for shooting quilts.  You always want something wider for that.  Some people like very wide angle lenses for landscapes.  You should get this if you are always shooting at 18 and want something wider.
The third is a fast prime as others have mentioned.  With your APS-C sensor I would look at the RF 35/1.8 rather than a 50mm.  It gives what is considered a normal field of view.  People get them for low light, but you are only buying a couple stops and the acceptable range of ISO may cover that.  It does allow a shallow depth of field if that is of interest.  I inherited the equivalent and find I do not use it much at all-I just use the standard zoom and push the ISO if the light is poor.
None of these is more versatile than what you have.  They all add capability in one direction or another beyond what you have.  The one lens I see that is more versatile than what you have is the RF-S 18-150.  It covers the range of your current lens and extends it a little over 3x in the long direction.  It is intended to be the only lens you use, or at least the one you use almost all the time so you don't have to change lenses.  It still has my complaint at the short end.  At the long end the loss of 150-210 is not that big.  You can deal with that in cropping.  The purists will tell you a lens with this much zoom range can't be as sharp and they are right.  If you show your photos on a screen you won't be able to tell the difference.  The purists will also ask why you bought a changeable lens camera, then bought a lens designed not to be changed.  This argument has weakened as the phone cameras have gotten better and driven the bridge cameras out of the market.
When you think about something like a lens, instead of thinking "how is it better" you should ask "what problem do I have that I hope this will solve".  What pictures that you want to take but can't get today will each of these allow you to take?
The previous paragraph is standard advice to give someone who asks your kind of question.  The problem is that when you have one of these capabilities you start to naturally see the pictures it brings.  You take them, play with them, and discover what you like.  It is hard.
